# ntfs-3g.usermap on Ubuntu 17

Tags: mount, ntfs

It appears as though ntfs-3g.usermap is absent from Ubuntu 17.10. I have ntfs-3g installed of course. Calling "dpkg -S ntfs-3g.usermap" returns no results.

Has it been replaced by something else in recent distributions or am I looking in the wrong place?

I would like make use of it to suppoer file permissions on an NTFS volume, as per [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/887502#887502).

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally stumbled across git the file  **`/bin/ntfsusermap`** . Apparently this executable has been renamed (from `ntfs-3g.usermap`) in more recent distributions, although I have not come across anything that mentions this, or why the change was made.